# RestKit 0.20 failed to fetch Entity

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am using restkit 0.2 to perform a post request to a server. Here is the setup code:

`- (void)setupRestKit
{
    //create RestKit object managers, one for API and one fore OAuth due to being seperate endpoings. API Object manager is default.
    RKObjectManager *apiObjectManager = [self instantiateAPIObjectManager];
    _oauthObjectManager = [self instantiateOAuthObjectManager];`

```
//create object store for core data persistence
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];

//provide store to object manager
_oauthObjectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
apiObjectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

//add default formatter for timestamp strings
NSTimeZone *UTC = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
[RKObjectMapping addDefaultDateFormatterForString:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" inTimeZone:UTC];

// Register mappings
[KaptureOAuthToken registerEntityMappingWithObjectManager:self.oauthObjectManager];

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

//create sqlite persistant store to cache data to disk
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"kapture.sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path
                                                                 fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                                                                      withConfiguration:nil
                                                                                options:@{
                                                                                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                                                                                          NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES
                                                                                        }
                                                                                  error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

//create in-memory cache so objects are not persisted more than once
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

//create contexts for core data objects
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
```

}

- (RKObjectManager *)instantiateAPIObjectManager
  {
  RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Environment sharedInstance].apiBaseURL]];

  //show network activity indicator when loading network resources
  [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

  //set api key as default http header for requests
  [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:[Environment sharedInstance].apiKey value:@"Api-Key"];

  //set http header for device type (i.e. iPhone 4) and version of the app
  NSString *deviceName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model], [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]];
  NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
  NSString *majorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
  [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"X-Requested-With" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", deviceName, majorVersion]];

  //set http header for api mime type
  [objectManager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:[Environment sharedInstance].apiAcceptenceHeader];

  objectManager.HTTPClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;

  return objectManager;
  }
- (RKObjectManager *)instantiateOAuthObjectManager
  {
  RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Environment sharedInstance].apiOAuthBaseURL]];

  //show network activity indicator when loading network resources
  [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

  objectManager.HTTPClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;

  return objectManager;
  }

-(void)setupNetworkCaching
{
    NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                                         diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                                             diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
}

And EntityMappings are configured via a category on NSManagedObject subclass  via these two methods

`+ (void)registerEntityMappingWithObjectManager:(RKObjectManager *)objectManager
{
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor;`

```
responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[self entityMappingUsingStore:objectManager.managedObjectStore]
                                                                  method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                             pathPattern:@"/"
                                                                 keyPath:@""
                                                             statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

}

- (RKEntityMapping *)entityMappingUsingStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)store
  {
  RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([KaptureOAuthToken class]) inManagedObjectStore:store];

  NSDictionary *attributesDict = @{@"access_token": @"accessToken",
                                   @"token_type": @"tokenType",
                                   @"expires": @"expirationDate",
                                   @"expires_in": @"expiresIn",
                                   @"refresh_token": @"refreshToken"};

  mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"accessToken"];

  [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:attributesDict];

  return mapping;
  }

My question is this: when I try to perform a POST request

[oauthObjectManager postObject:nil path:@"/" parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            completion(YES, nil, mappingResult);
        });
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            [self notifyLoginError:error forNetwork:network];
        });
    }];

I get an expected response from the server and everything seems to go through fine, but I get this error in the command line. 

`2013-08-22 17:29:11.949 Kapture[25335:1007] W restkit.core_data.cache:RKEntityByAttributeCache.m:173 Failed to load entity cache. Failed to execute fetch request:  (entity: KaptureOAuthToken; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSDictionaryResultType; includesPendingChanges: NO; propertiesToFetch: ((
    "(), name accessToken, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity KaptureOAuthToken, renamingIdentifier accessToken, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)",
    "(), name objectID, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity (null), renamingIdentifier objectID, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}"
)); )`

It seems that it cannot find the entity in the cache but I'm really not sure. Any information is appreciated as always!

Comment: Can you edit this post so it becomes clearer? There's way too much information without proper formatting.. it is hard to understand it this way.

Comment: Please format your code as it is currently unreadable.